# How to make async task repeated synchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a Node.js background task that I want to run, which will make multiple API calls. My end goal is to have a main asynchronous loop that, when complete, starts again. Each of the API calls are asynchronous, however I want to execute them in order.

I've considered doing the following:

1. Adding `await` to each of the function calls
2. Making the loop `async`
3. Calling the loop after the async functions finish
4. Doing 1 master call to `loop` at the start of the program to initialize it

Example:

```
var loop = async function() {
   await asyncFunctionOne();
   await asyncFunctionTwo();
   await asyncFunctionThree();

   loop();
}

loop();
```

For context, I'm running this background task on a Node.js web application, so this loop should be running asynchronously on the side.

I'm wondering if the above example is a valid approach — if I keep this running indefinitely, would this take up a lot of memory? I'm not entirely sure how stack overflows work, but would this cause a stack overflow or any other sort of issues? If there's a better way of writing this code, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you show runs the loop once:

```
var loop = async function() {
   await asyncFunctionOne();
   await asyncFunctionTwo();
   await asyncFunctionThree();
}

loop();
```

If you want to run it over and over, you can just have it call itself when done:

```
var loop = async function() {
   await asyncFunctionOne();
   await asyncFunctionTwo();
   await asyncFunctionThree();
   // after short delay, call itself again
   // delay can be removed if you really want to hammer external resources
   //     as much as possible, but usually, you don't want to put that much
   //     load on external resources
   setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}

loop();
```

This is a perfectly fine thing to do in node.js.  There is no stack build-up, there is no memory build-up (assuming your functions themselves don't do something that purposely accumulates memory).

> I'm wondering if the above example is a valid approach

Yes, it's a valid approach.

> For context, I'm running this background task on a Node.js web application, so this loop should be running asynchronously on the side.

Keep in mind that node.js runs your Javsacript single threaded so when one of these functions has some Javascript to run, that's happening in the foreground, not the background.  But as long there's nothing CPU intensive in those functions and they are mostly just asynchronous I/O calls, it will not particularly interfere with the other things your node.js server may want to do.  For fully background operation that has no impact at all on the main node.js event loop, you would want to either fire up another node.js child_process to run this loop or use the newer [Worker thread API](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

> if I keep this running indefinitely, would this take up a lot of memory?

If your functions themselves do not purposely accumulate memory into some persistent higher scoped variables, then this should not be accumulating memory.  There is no stack build-up and garbage collection will cleanup any temporary memory usage.  The memory usage should ramp up to a steady state value after a few iterations and not continually rise after that.

> but would this cause a stack overflow or any other sort of issues?

No stack overflow here.  Each iteration of `loop()` finishes before the next one runs.

> If there's a better way of writing this code, please let me know.

To make alternate suggestions, we'd need to know exactly what the real world problem is that you're solving and see the actual code.  As far as a theoretical solution, this is fine.  Optimizing a solution requires seeing the actual problem and the actual code.  It's hard to optimize a theoretical problem.

For example, this smells like you're polling some external resource(s) for changes or updates which is, in general, inefficient.  Whether there's a more efficient way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do depends entirely upon how the specific resources you're polling work and what exactly you're doing with the data when you get updates and how often those updates are really needed in the context of your actual application/client.

Comment: Why the delay?  Why not run the inside call to `loop` immediately?

Comment: @pwilcox - That's up to the OP whether to have a delay or not.  Usually, in some sort of infinite loop like this, you don't want to be hammering your external resources as fast as possible so some sort of delay between iterations is desirable.  As such, I thought I'd show how that would be done.  The delay can be set to any time or removed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I accidentally made a typo in my question and didn't include the last line of the loop function, which then calls loop again. Basically, I want to wait until all 3 functions are done, then immediately call it again.

The real question I was asking is whether or not this causes a stack overflow, or if there's any downside to this, because it seems like `loop()` is called inside the curly brace, therefore the function isn't finishing. But, according to your answer, this is false. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks so much!

Comment: @JamsheedMistri -  Because your `loop` function is `async` there is no stack build-up when you call `loop()` again at the end.  The prior loop function has already returned (it returned a promise when it hit the first `await`).  If you did `await loop()`, then there would be a build-up of promises (not stack, but promise objects).  But, since you did not put `await` in from of your internal call to `loop()`, there is no promise buildup either.  It's also possible that tail call optimization would remove the stack buildup if your function wasn't `async`, but it's hard to rely on that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh, that totally makes sense. Thank you so much! :)